# Determine if a resultset exists quickly

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to determine if a resultset exists very quickly. At the moment, I'm doing a count - this is taking roughly 55ms, which is unfeasable.The table has ~100k records - I don't care if it has 2, 5, 100k rows that fit a query; I care if it has 0 or 1. Maybe 2 in certain situations.

Is there a way to do this? Would limiting a count using ROWCOUNT (so it only counts about the first 2 rows it finds) speed up the count at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you need just to check existence I'd go with 
`SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM [your query])` ...

For "top-n" queries there are quite a few alternatives - https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries . Note, some of them may have side effects ; for instance, `where rownum < :value` can change optimizer mode to FIRST_ROWS.

Comment: top-n-queries are a rather bad idea because it involves   retrieving and sorting all data.

Comment: the exist clause is fine if you only want to check if there exists at least onw result row. I think the execution plan will be the same as the execution plan of `select count(*)
from ...
where (...)
and rownum<=1`

Comment: what does side effect mean in that context? the optimizer mode of what will be changed?

Comment: @miracle173 : optimizer mode for this particular query. surely it won't affect settings for instance or session - http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_tuning_rownum_equals_one.htm .    Other optimizer modes - (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams145.htm#REFRN10145 ) .  Surely, `exists` as the name implies is useful to check for existence.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from ...
where (...)
and rownum<=3
```

return 3 if there are 3 or more rows and the number of rows if there are 2 or less rows. I think this statement tells Oracle exactly what you want.

Maybe the use of a cursor is possble, too .If you use a cursor and want fetch the first three rows and the close the cursor, then you should give oracle a hint like `/*+ FIRST_ROWS(3) */`. But the `rownum<=3` query is the more precise way. I cannot see a way there you case usefully apply ROWCOUNT. Bear in mind that ther is and `SQL%ROWCOUNT` and a `cursorname%ROWCOUNT` the first returns the number of rows retrieved/effected by a SELECT, DELETE; UPDATE, INSER,... statement. It return null for the cursor statement. `cursorname%ROWCOUNT` retunr the rownumber of the row you have just fetched. ROWCOUNT is desctribed in the [PL/SQL manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#sthref535)

Comment: Would this be faster?

Comment: You could test with your own data?

Comment: @Daniel: this query defines exactly what you want: check if there  are 0,1,2 or more rows, It is up to the optimizer to generate a plan that retrieves the data  as fast as possible. Please publish the results of your measurements.

Comment: Newbie question; what's a good way to get those measurements? Right now I'm just writing timestamps to a table.

Comment: I use sqlplus for such measurements. it has a `set timing on` command. It also has a `set autotrace on explain statistics` command that display an execution plan and the some statistics  data. the user must have granted the plustrace role to use this.